# Strange, random inconsistencies in RSA decryption of characters in an RSA python program I wrote

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, rsa

I wrote the following RSA tool in python and got it working, then I realized the way it was originally written would leave the encrypted message vunerable to frequency analysis. I've been upgrading it so that instead of encrypting letter by letter it splits a string of ASCII values into equal chuncks and encrypts the chuncks. I slowly worked out all the problems with splitting and reassembling the message, but once I got the decrypted message out 4 of the 19 characters were wrong, but the rest were right. I used 89 and 97 as the p and q values to get 2111 for e, 8633 for N, and 6335 for d while testing. Pub Key being [2111, 8633] and Priv Key [6335, 8633]. The message to be encrypted and decrypted was, "Im going on a Trip!". The ASCII code before decryption as a list split into individual characters is                                  ['073', '109', '032', '103', '111', '105', '110', '103', '032', '111', '110', '032', '097', '032', '084', '114', '105', '112', '033']
so I should be getting the same list back out on the decryption end, but instead I'm getting ['073', '100', '399', '103', '111', '105', '110', '103', '032', '111', '110', '032', '010', '702', '084', '114', '105', '112', '033']. As you can see, the second, third, thirteenth, and fourteenth characters are incorrect, but the rest are correct. Below is the program. All the random 'print' functions are leftover from my troubleshooting. I can't find the problem and would love some help and any suggestions or other errors/ you may find. Thanks.

```
import random
import math


def create_key_set():
    p = int(input('Insert prime number for value of p: '))
    q = int(input('Insert new prime number for value of q: '))
    N = p * q
    y = (p-1) * (q-1)
    while True:
        cop = random.randint(2, (y-1))
        gcd = math.gcd(cop, y)
        if gcd == 1:
            break
    e = cop
    pubkey = [e, N]
    d = pow(e, -1, y)
    privkey = [d, N]
    print('Public Key is: ', pubkey)
    print('Private Key is: ', privkey)

def encrypt_message(e, N, A):
    #convert message to list of characters
    M = list(A)
    #convert list of characters to list of ASCII values
    M = list(map(ord, M))
    print(M)
    #convert list of ASCII values to list of strings
    M = list(map(str, M))
    #pad list of strings with zeros to make length divisible by 3
    M = list(map(lambda x: x.zfill(3), M))
    print(M)
    #join list into single string
    M = ''.join(M)
    #pad string with zeros to make length divisible by 4
    y = len(M)
    z = (math.floor(y / 4) * 4) + 4
    M = M.zfill(z)
    #split string into list of strings of length 4
    o = []
    while M:
        o.append(M[:4])
        M = M[4:]
    print(o)
    #convert list of strings to list of integers
    M = list(map(int, o))
    #convert list of integers to list of encrypted integers
    M =list(map(lambda x:pow(x, e, N), M))
    #convert list of encrypted integers to list of strings
    M = list(map(str, M))
    #pad list of strings with zeros to make length divisible by 6
    M = list(map(lambda x: x.zfill(6), M))
    print(M)
    #join list of strings into single string
    seq = list(map(len, M))
    M = ''.join(M)
    print('Encrypted message: ', M)
    print('Decryption Map: ', seq)
    return M, seq

def decrypt_message(d, N, encrypted_message):
    #convert encrypted message to string
    C = str(encrypted_message)
    M = str(C)
    #split string into list of strings of length 6
    res = []
    while M:
        res.append(M[:6])
        M = M[6:]
    print(res)
    #convert list of strings to list of integers
    M = list(map(int, res))
    #convert list of integers to list of decrypted integers
    M =list(map(lambda x:pow(x, d, N), M))
    #convert list of decrypted integers to list of strings
    M = list(map(str, M))
    #pad list of strings with zeros to make length divisible by 4
    M = list(map(lambda x: x.zfill(4), M))
    #join list of strings into single string
    M = ''.join(M)
    #convert string to list of strings of length 4
    res2 = []
    while M:
        res2.append(M[:4])
        M = M[4:]
    print(res2)
    # convert list of strings to string
    M = ''.join(res2)
    #convert string to integer
    M = int(M)
    print(M)
    # pad integer with zeros to make length divisible by 3
    y = len(str(M))
    z = (math.floor(y / 3) * 3) + 3
    M = str(M).zfill(z)
    # convert integer to list of integers of length 3
    res3 = []
    while M:
        res3.append(M[:3])
        M = M[3:]
    print(res3)
    #convert list of integers to list of characters
    M = list(chr(i) for i in M)
    #join list of characters into single string
    M = "".join(M)
    print('Decrypted message: ',M)

def main_menu():
    print('Select an option:')
    print('1. Create Key Set')
    print('2. Encrypt Message')
    print('3. Decrypt Message')
    option = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
    if option == 1:
       create_key_set()
       main_menu()
    elif option == 2:
        e = int(input('Insert first number of public key: '))
        N = int(input('Insert second number of public key: '))
        A = input('Input message to be encrypted: ')
        encrypt_message(e, N, A)
        main_menu()
    elif option == 3:
        d = int(input('Insert first number of private key: '))
        N = int(input('Insert second number of private key: '))
        encrypted_message = input('Insert encrypted message: ')
        decrypt_message(d, N, encrypted_message)
        main_menu()
    else: print('Invalid option, try again.')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main_menu()
```

I'm sure its not written the best as this is my first time trying to make a complete program. Also, excuse my manic use of comments and nonsensical variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of 3-digit character codes

```
['073', '109', '032', '103', '111', '105', '110', '103', '032', '111', '110', '032', '097', '032', '084', '114', '105', '112', '033']
```

produces the list of 4-digit 'chunks'

```
['0000', '7310', '9032', '1031', '1110', '5110', '1030', '3211', '1110', '0320', '9703', '2084', '1141', '0511', '2033']
```

Notice two of those values (9032 and 9703) exceed your RSA modulus (N) of 8633. **RSA encryption does not work for values >= the modulus.** Because m^e mod n and c^d mod n are both done mod n, any plaintext value >= n is effectively taken mod n, thus your decryption produces the *different* list of chunks

```
['0000', '7310', '0399', '1031', '1110', '5110', '1030', '3211', '1110', '0320', '1070', '2084', '1141', '0511', '2033']
```

which you can see 'dechunks' to the partially-wrong list of characters you report, plus two extra leading '000' characters you did not report -- but code 000 is null and I go back to paper-tape days so I'm used to ignoring extra nulls :-)

If this is not simply a learning exercise (which would be valid, it is something you can learn from) and you hope to develop something to actually be used, you should also know:

- using RSA with such small values for p and q (and thus n) is totally insecure. Real implementations for many decades have used binary arithmetic and not decimal, so it is customary to talk about RSA key (and cryptogram) sizes in bits (binary digits) rather than decimal digits, although mathematically either can be converted to the other, and for convenience we often use bit sizes that are a power of 2 or a small multiple thereof; since about 2010 most standards have required a minimum size of 2048 bits (2^11) for n, although actual breaks known in the open community have only reached about 800 bits (the closed crypto community, i.e. mostly governments, is assumed to always be somewhat ahead but we don't know by how much), and some highly-constrained applications (mostly smartcards) still accept 1024 bits (2^10) or thereabouts. (These correspond to about 616 and 308 decimal digits respectively.)
- using RSA without padding is insecure; see wikipedia. In particular 'encrypting' unpadded zero or one is always totally insecure (although the *algorithm* works), and 'encrypting' any value small relative to the modulus almost always is -- although this is harder to see with a uselessly small modulus like yours
- using RSA directly on user data that can vary significantly like files or emails or just user text is very fragile and inefficient; *most* real schemes use hybrid encryption where RSA is used only to encrypt (and decrypt) the key (which is a small, fixed size) for a symmetric encryption scheme, again see wikipedia
- having the two primes p and q close to each other is insecure. For the key sizes now accepted it is sufficient to choose p and q independently at random within the desired range, and the probability they will be too close is negligible, but decades ago when sizes like 1024-bit or even 768-bit and 512-bit were accepted it was common (and in some cases required) to explicitly check for and reject this case
- using naive decryption c^d mod n is unnecessarily inefficient; for a uselessly small modulus this doesn't matter but for sizes that are actually secure you need the more efficient Chinese-remainder implementation; again see wikipedia
- simply using python's 3-arg pow, although convenient, may be insecure if/when so-called 'side-channel' attacks like power and timing are possible. Traditionally cryptography only worried about attacks on messages in transit, i.e. between the endpoints, but nowadays there are often attacks on the endpoints as well. This gets into whole complicated areas that aren't directly about programming and are off-topic here, but you should learn about them if you want to write something actually secure.

Finally, and more generally applicable, writing programs today limited to ASCII is widely viewed as hopelessly outdated, if not actually unethical. Essentially all languages and standards and nearly all systems from the last 30 years, including python, support Unicode, with a vastly larger character repertoire that does not fit in 3-decimal-digit codes and thus won't work in your scheme -- even if your scheme didn't have the other flaws above.